# How to Add MetaData to Mp3's at Points in the File?

Tags: mp3

How would you add annotations/metadata to an mp3 file at certain points of the file, much like how SoundCloud does it?  For example, if I had a 3 minute long mp3, and I wanted to add an annotation at the 1:10 mark of the file with a note of "Here's the main idea".  Then mp3 players that know these annotations exist could look for them while reading the mp3 file and playing the sound.

Comment: i didnt get what you mean by annotation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want chapter Markers?

as on http://id3v2-chap-tool.sourceforge.net/

Chapters in this context could be any of the following:

chapters within an audiobook

articles within a podcast

individual tracks within a multi-track audio file

you will need VLC Media Player, cause most Players dont show Chapters.

Comment: Thanks - I will take a look.  Any idea if iTunes shows chapters?

Comment: This appears to be just what I was looking for, thanks.  I'll need to figure out which players show chapters.

Comment: iTunes will show chapters, 
i needed that too, i will look for an Android App that shows chapters.